# Get jupyter notebook kernel ID in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When starting a jupyter notebook server and create a new notebook instance, I can see logs from console:

```
[I 2023-05-04 11:28:34.937 ServerApp] Kernel restarted: 1f91e40e-ac1b-4cc5-b655-91e490a5363c
```

The value `1f91e40e-ac1b-4cc5-b655-91e490a5363c` is what I want.

I tried to use the following methods in the notebook:

```
from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
kernel = get_ipython().kernel
kernel.ident
```

but it returns a new value everytime I execute it. It seems ident keeps changing. So I guess that's not what I want. When I restart a kernel, the log shows:

```
Kernel restarted: 1f91e40e-ac1b-4cc5-b655-91e490a5363c
```

see, the same id.
I am looking for methods to get this value, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Issue [1004](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/issues/1004) shows two possibilities, one of which is:

```py
import ipykernel
import re
kernel_id = re.search('kernel-(.*).json', ipykernel.connect.get_connection_file()).group(1)
```